# Dual boot with windows 10. Selecting windows in grub restarts computer. (also partitioning?)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

So I had a few issues installing ubuntu in the first place. I have a 3TB hard drive so I had to repartition using gdisk. I had to change my Windows partition from mdos to gpt. Then I selected to install Ubuntu alongside windows while installing from USB with no issues. Now when I start my computer it loads grub by default which is great. But the problem is when I select Windows from the menu, my computer restarts and loads grub again in a never ending loop. I'm pretty new to this and am trying to figure this out as I go basically. Did I screw anything up when partitioning? And most importantly, how do I fix this??

Comment: Why did you change the partitioning from MBR to GPT? does the computer boot EFI or Legacy mode? Legacy mode can not read a GPT disk. also windows installed on a MBR disk likely doesn't have GPT drivers installed. You could try converting back, but if you really want GPT then you'll have to reinstall windows.

Comment: I have the exact same [problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/965943/507217), looks like the cause is that Windows 10 is in UEFI-mode but my Ubuntu is mistakenly installed in BIOS-mode