# Dual-boot problem with Windows 10: booting to Windows 10 restarts the machine

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, boot-repair

I'm trying to fix a problem on someone's laptop. The problem is that after installing Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, the GRUB doesn't boot into previously-installed Windows 10. The Windows 10 **is** among the GRUB menu items, but when selecting the Windows 10 menu item, the system doesn't boot into Windows and **restarts** instead.

I was also receiving `signature` errors while playing around with GRUB command line options.

I tried [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) but it couldn't resolve the problem. The `boot-repair` report is available at the following link:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/25763771/

The Boot-Repair Boot Info Script shows this at the end of the Boot Info Script:

```
update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 10 (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found Windows 10 (loader) on /dev/sda2
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda7': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda7' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
mount /dev/sda7 : Error code 12
mount -r /dev/sda7 /mnt/boot-sav/sda7
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda7': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda7' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
mount -r /dev/sda7 : Error code 12
```

---

I ran:

```
$ sudo mkfs.ntfs -Q /dev/sda7
```

And the signature messages at the end of `boot-repair` report got resolved:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/25764357/

---

On GRUB command line, accessible by pressing `e` when GRUB menu is display, when I enter the following commands:

```
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,gpt2'
    chainloader /bootmgr
```

I receive the following error message:

```
>  Booting a command list
> Error: invalid signature
>  Press any key to continue ...
```

And when I press any key, the machine reboots

---

I think the problem is mentioned in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/654746/507217). The `CSM` option is `enabled` on my firmware setup. Therefore, I think Ubuntu is installed with GRUB in BIOS mode instead of UEFI mode. And my disk uses GPT, therefore Windows 10 can only be loaded by a UEFI boot loader not a BIOS boot loader.

What I'm going to do now, is to disable `CSM` on my firmware setup and then boot with Ubuntu live DVD and then try to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode.

The problem is further explained [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

Comment: @karel It solved the signature messages at the end of `boot-repair` report, yet, I cannot boot into Windows 10, and it still restarts the computer

Comment: Please take a look at this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix I don't believe that it's an exact duplicate of your question because you also solved the signature error, but it may help from here on.

Comment: @karel Great, I'm going to work on it

Comment: Reinstalling Ubuntu in UEFI-mode will help you a lot!

Comment: @mook765 Right, I'm installing Ubuntu in UEFI-mode

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)